# I am trying to import selenium webdriver, scripting using Python IDLE 3.7 64bit: the command i used is "from selenium import webdriver"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have installed selenium (3.14), pip is running fine. But when i try to import webdriver: "from selenium import webdriver". I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver

  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.14.0-py3.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa

  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.14.0-py3.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 29, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver

  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.14.0-py3.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .remote_connection import RemoteConnection

  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.14.0-py3.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 24, in <module>
    import urllib3

  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3-0.3-py3.7.egg\urllib3\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, get_host, connection_from_url ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'connectionpool'
```

Comment: Looks like some dependencies were missed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using Windows 7. Do you know what dependencies are missing ?

Comment: They should be listed on Selenium's package page on PyPI or it's public repository if any

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/README.md  Make sure you have all the necessary actions done like having `chromedriver` on path

Comment: I have installed chrome driver and saved in the "scripts" folder as well. followed the instructions on PyPI page. Still getting error. Any help is appreciated. I am kind of new to the environment. Thank you

Comment: I have resolved this by downgrading my python version from 3.7 to 2.6. It worked for me. Thank you for your suggestions